# Picking image from gallery and set to imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, cursor, gallery

I'm trying to pick image from gallery and set it to imageview.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            Log.e("1","1");
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Log.e("2","2");

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Log.e("3","3");

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            Log.e("4","4");
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Log.e("5", "5");

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            Log.e("6","6");
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.e("7","7");
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            Log.e("8","8");
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

In logs it shows only third log and after that shows toast which in catch. I'm using Samsung S4, and android version is 5.0.1. 
I think, problem is about cursor, but can't fix it. Please help me.

Comment: Did you add permissions for reading external storage?

Comment: print the stacktrace in your catch block and post it here.

Comment: i put this two permission before activity "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <uses-permission-sdk23 android:name="android.provider.MediaStore" />"

Comment: this is catch exception " E/e: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code I have used for Picking Gallery Image then display it to `ImageView`. You can use according to your need.

Here is method for opening Gallery Intent.

```
private static final int GALLERY_PHOTO = 111;

private void pickGalleryImage() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GALLERY_PHOTO);
}
```

then your `onActivityResult()` method should be like this. in this method `mContext` refers Context of `Activity`. if `Activity` name is `MainActivity` then you can use `MainActivity.this`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (requestCode == GALLERY_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          if (data.getData() != null) {
                String filePath = GetFilePathFromDevice.getPath(mContext, data.getData());
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
           }      
      } 
}
```

Here is `GetFilePathFromDevice` class used in `onActivityResult()` method to get file path of selected image from Gallery.

```
public final class GetFilePathFromDevice {

    /**
     * Get file path from URI
     *
     * @param context context of Activity
     * @param uri     uri of file
     * @return path of given URI
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: i tried this also, put try catch , and it gave this exception "android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()"

Comment: what is 'mContext' in ActivityResult, did you initialized it?

Comment: what is name of Activity?

Comment: then try MainActivity.this instead of mContext

Comment: now it gives another exception, "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: the same problem, in Cursor query line.

Comment: this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
"